# How to change color scheme world class in java files

Tags: java, sublimetext2

I would like to change the color that is the word class in java files. I am using eiffel color scheme. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the theme file. Try in

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Eiffel.tmTheme
```

[See here](https://superuser.com/questions/794833/editing-a-sublime-theme-how-to-know-which-key-string-corresponds-to-which-text) how to find the scope value associated with the class keyword, then if it is for example `storage.type.class.java` add a new `<dict>` item for that one

Comment: It is "Storage". With class, it also changes int keyword. Can I make different colors?